# Connect to FTP via Nautilus connect to server

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, nautilus, ftp

I want to connect other ubuntu machines on my network. I use Nautilus FTP connection manager for it, but it ended up with connection refused by server error.

I install `vsftpd` but it still shows some error

I am using Ubunut 12.04LTS 64bit.[image]

Answer (score 2):

My best guess would be that there is nothing wrong with Nautilus, but something wrong with your network setup or with the setup of the remote computer's FTP server.

I will assume that the computer you try to connect to :

- Is connected on the network on the same subnet
- Is running :)
- Has a ftp server installed (vsftp, for instance)

First, you must ensure that network connection between both computer is OK. First thing is to ping the remote computer (`ping 192.168.1.198` in a terminal). If the remote computer is answering to the ping, let's move on. Otherwise, you'll have to set your internet correction correctly so that the two computer "see" each other.

Second, you must check that the FTP server is up and running on the remote computer. Have a look at the configuration in the file /etc/vsftpd.conf to check that everything is setup as it should. In particular, check the port on which the FTP server is running. If you have a line with "listen_port=x" with x being NOT 21, then it is not using the default FTP port. Each time you change something in the settings you must reload it in vsftpd, using `sudo service vsftpd reload` in a terminal.

In order to check that the FTP connection is working, you can use the simple command line client. Just type `ftp 192.168.1.198` in a terminal and it will try to connect. This way you can check if the problem comes from the FTP connection itself. If you have a different port that 21, you must set it here too (look at the man of the ftp command for this).

Hope this helps,

Ben

Comment: yes i have installed  vsftp and i am on same subnet

Comment: there isn't any line like listen_port but there is listen_ipv6

Comment: And can you connect in command line with the ftp program ?

Comment: Also, have a look at this page about IPv4 and IPv6 in vsftpd : https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=574837

Comment: No, in terminal it shows connection refused

Comment: Then the pb is not about Nautilus, but the ftp connection. Did you look at the IPv4 / IPv6 possible conflict that I sent before ?